# Simple Sort function not working. Suggestions?

Tags: sorting, processing

```java
void sort_records_by_id (int []indices, int []students_id )
{
 for (int k = 1; k<students_id.length; k++)
 {

   for (int j = k; j>0 && students_id[j]<students_id[j-1]; j--)
   {
    int place_holder = indices[j];
    indices[j] = indices [j-1];
    indices[j-1] = place_holder;
   }
 }
}
```

Hi,

I have to create a function that is able to sort an array of integers, not by changing and rearranging its contents, but by changing the order of integers in another array of integers called indexes. So, I would have an array with a series of ids such as: Lets call this id" [#] represents index [0]10001 12001 [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kALll.png)12334 [3]14332 [4]999999 [5]10111
There is a corresponding array, with integer values [#] is the index Lets call this arr [0]0 11 [2}2 [3]3 [4]4 [5]5 So that they correspond to the indexes we have in the other array.
Now, we must change the order of "arr", such that the elements are in such an order that it corresponds to the order of indexes in array id in sorted order. Note, array id is not changed in any way. 
So, we can print the ids to the console in ascending order, by using a for loop, the values of arr, and array id.

[image]

Please, I would really appreciate if you would be able to provide advice without creating a very complex function. I would just like to alter my existing function I created so that it works.

This is the output of my function so far:
[image]

Any input or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Pick one language.

Comment: Is this a java or a c++ question? Please decide.

Comment: Porcessing if possible. If not processing than C++ please. But not too complicated.

Comment: I appreciate the extremely helpful and dedicated community here at Stackoverflow, but please understand I am a beginner, and can't understand overly complex syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When indexing students_id array, don't use j and j-1, but instead of this -> indices[j] and indices[j-1]. Thanks to that, you will change order in indices array using students_id array to get values to comparison.

```
for (int j = k; j>0 && students_id[indices[j]]<students_id[indices[j-1]]; j--)
```

Also I would change loop into

```
void sort_records_by_id (int []indices, int []students_id )
{
 for (int k = 1; k<students_id.length; ++k)
 {

   for (int j = 0; j<k; ++j)
   {
     if(students_id[indices[j]]>students_id[indices[j+1]]) {
       int place_holder = indices[j];
       indices[j] = indices [j+1];
       indices[j+1] = place_holder;
     }
   }
 }
}
```

The simplest bubble sort - that's what comes to my mind.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I really appreciate it. 
However, I am getting 0 5 8 7 2 3 1 6 9 4, which is not the correct answer apparently. Thanks again though, I appreciate the insight

Comment: I have also added suggestion about loop condition.

Comment: I have a question to you.
How to get to know that the order in console output [0]0 [1]2 [2]1 [3]3 [4]5 [5]4 ... is correct?
When I'm trying to order it by myself I got: [index]student_id    ->>>
[0]10001 [1]10111 [2]10332 [3]12034 [4]12334 [5]14332 [6]20001 [7]20101 [8]99991 [9]99999

which is 0 5 8 7 2 3 1 6 9 4 as you have mentioned in previous comment

Comment: Thanks!
Basically, I am not allowed to change the order of the actual ID array. I just have to change the order of the index array so that its order and entries corresponds to the descending order of the student array. This explanation can be found in the picture above. 
So the output of the index array should be 0 6 4 5 8 1 7 3 2 9

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but the new loop doesn't work either.